# Start Next.js apps on Ubuntu server reboot with pm2

Tags: next.js, pm2

`pm2` is really great for running my Next.js app on my Linode cloud server, running Ubuntu 20. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to run my Next.js apps on a system reboot.

What I have been doing is going in and using:

```sh
pm2 start npm --name "my app" --start manually.
```

So how do I have it run automatically on reboot?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pm2 startup` to generate a Systemd service. [Docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/).

Comment: That does show how to startup pm2, but how do I start the nextjs app?

Comment: If your app is currently running and you've generated the service with `pm2 startup`, run `pm2 save` to save all the currently running apps so they also get restarted: [docs here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#saving-current-process-list).

Comment: I tried getting this to work. I still have to manually start my apps after reboot. I guess it just isn't clear to me what I need to do

Comment: You ran `pm2 startup`, generated the service file, had the app running, ran `pm2 save`, and it didn't work? Is there anything in `~/.pm2/dump.pm2` (or wherever PM2_HOME is set to)?

Comment: I think what I don’t understand is what or where do I pit the service file?

Comment: dump.pm2 is in the ~/.pm2 folder

Comment: When you ran `pm2 startup` it should've put the service in the right place (probably `/etc/systemd/system/` since you should be on systemd) and enabled it. The output from running the command would've included the location and what it did to enable it, or an error (such as `systemctl: not found` or any other errors). To debug, [this section of the docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#systemd-installation-checking) should be helpful.

Comment: ok, a dumb moment on my part. I didn't copy and paste the script it gave me to run. I thought I was supposed to copy and paste it into some startup file. I think it will work this time.